# SSRS 'My Subscriptions' is empty

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are running SQL Server 2008 and have set up SSRS to allow a small selection of users to run reports on the database. Email subscriptions are functioning correctly and relevant subscriptions will appear in the 'Manage' dialog for each report. However, the 'My Subscriptions' page always appears blank.

I have had trouble finding a record of this issue having been resolved elsewhere; however, I have found [some information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156307.aspx) stating that the 'My Subscriptions' page lists only subscriptions that are 'owned' by the current user and that 'owner' is effectively the creator of the subscription. This leads me to think that perhaps there is a third-party/system account creating the subscription in the user's place, though I'm not sure what the source of this would be. I've checked Configuration Manager and there's no execution account specified.

Any help in identifying the source of this issue is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Who is actually creating the subscriptions? Is it the users themselves? As you note, subscriptions will only appear in "My Subscriptions" for the user that CREATES the subscription.

Comment: Users are creating subscriptions themselves, yes. They may be creating them on behalf of third parties, but only the creators are the ones attempting to view the subscriptions. Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a report server running in Native mode. Can you check what Report Manager "role" the users have been assigned, and then check that this role has the task "Manage Individual Subscriptions" assigned?

Comment: Hi - The report server is indeed running in Native mode. I've checked that the users' roles have the 'Manage Individual Subscriptions' task and also double-checked that the subscriptions are owned by the expected users in the report server Subscriptions table. Everything seems to be as expected, but the My Subscriptions dialog is still empty.

Comment: Managed to find the root cause - have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cracked it! The users were authenticating in Report Manager as `SOMEDOMAIN\MyUser`, while the ReportServer database was storing the users without the domain.

All I had to do was prepend the domain to the applicable users' names in `[ReportServer].[dbo].Users`.